# Multiuser XML document "database" for asp.net app

Tags: .net, asp.net, xml, multithreading, mutex

I was thinking about a way to allow multiple users to get CRUD access to an XML document in an asp.net app.  The operations would obviously have to be made under the assumption of a multithreaded environment.

For perf reasons, would it make sense to cache the document, and use a mutex on that cached version?  When would changes be flushed to the physical XML document?

Any and all recommendations are appreciated (also "use a database" isn't an option at this point unfortunately)

Comment: I know you said a database was not an option, but what about a light weight object database, such as db4o ? No installation required, data in a single file, and many of your concerns about concurrency and storing would be solved.

Answer (score 0):

It certainly makes sense to cache the XML document, so you do not need to read it from disk for each user / request. You should synchronize access to it. A good idea would be to encapsulate access in a single class, and use a [ReaderWriterLockSlim](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.readerwriterlockslim.aspx) for synchronization. When reading data, acquire a read lock and read from memory. When writing, acquire a write lock, write data and replace the in-memory copy.

Answer (score 0):

You could serialize your cached version of your DB object to the disk (as binary) after every transaction and only write the XML at certain intervals.